# ¿Por qué no muestra datos completos al importar de Excel a un dataset?

Tags: c#, excel

favor si alguien me puede ayudar con este caso, estoy importando datos de un excel a un datagridview (dgv), en el excel tengo un campo llamado "Talla" donde hay números y letras(40,30,42,M,L,XL, etc), el problema es que al importar en el dataset (dt) visualizo que en este campo solo me muestra números y los demás vacíos, asi tal cual lo manda al dgv, como podría mostrar todos los datos de este campo? nose a que se debe, los demás campos si me muestra completos.

```
if (openfile1.ShowDialog() == System.Windows.Forms.DialogResult.OK)
            {
                if (openfile1.FileName.Equals("") == false)
                {
                    string ruta = openfile1.FileName;
                    OleDbConnection conn = new OleDbConnection("Provider=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0;data source=" + ruta + ";Extended Properties='Excel 12.0 Xml;HDR=Yes'");
                    OleDbDataAdapter MyDataAdapter = new OleDbDataAdapter("Select * from [" + nombreHoja + "$]", conn);
                    DataSet dt = new DataSet();
                    MyDataAdapter.Fill(dt);
                    //dgv.DataSource = dt.Tables[0];

                    //Elimina las filas vacías (System.Data.DataSetExtensions - AsEnumerable)
                    dt.Tables[0].AsEnumerable().Where(row => row.ItemArray.All(field => field == null || field == DBNull.Value || field.Equals(string.Empty) || string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(field.ToString()))).ToList().ForEach(row => row.Delete());
                    dt.Tables[0].AcceptChanges();

                    //Inserta al Datagridview
                    foreach (DataRow item in dt.Tables[0].Rows)
                    {
                        dgv.Rows.Add(item["Codigo"].ToString(), item["Codigo"].ToString(), "", item["Almacen"].ToString(), item["Color"].ToString(), item["Talla/N°"].ToString(),"0", item["Medida"].ToString(), item["Cantidad"].ToString(), item["Costo"].ToString(), item["Total"].ToString());
                       
                    }


                    

                }
```

ESTO ME MUESTRA EL DATASET:
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

ESTO ES LO QUE DEBE MOSTRAR DEL EXCEL
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: Revisa que, en el Excel, la columna D tenga toda un formato de texto o General. Pareciera que la interpreta como número y ahí se traga todos los que no lo son

Comment: Tenías razón Alfabravo, la columna D tenía otro formato, ya lo corregí y ahora si me muestra todos los datos, muchas gracias x su tiempo y disculpen que no me haya dado cuenta.

Answer (score 1):

Lo mas fácil es hacer lo siguiente;

dgGrilla.Rows.Add(col1, col2, col3, etc);

Entonces, te lees los datos desde un DB o desde un excel o un archivo plano. Como sea, en un ciclo:

Yo ocupo puro foreach, en este caso o.Items es un `List<Detalle>`

```
foreach (Factura.Detalle det in o.Items)
{

 dgGrilla.Rows.Add(det.Folio, det.Descripcion, det.Precio, etc...);

}
```

Lo mismo para un archivo plano separado por comas

```
foreach (string linea in o.Lineas)
{
   var datos = linea.Split(',');
   dgGrilla.Rows.Add(datos[0], datos[1], datos[2], etc...);

}
```

En caso de querer usar excel tambien puedes hacerlo de una manera similar usando la integracion que tienen los productos de Microsoft, yo prefiero usar archivos planos (.csv)

Genera un .csv y verifica que los datos esta en el archivo, luego has la prueba cargando los datos en la grilla y verifícalo en tu interfaz.
También puedes inspeccionar las variables y verificar que los datos esten en las variables que cargas.

Yo prefiero asegurarme con los .csv por que puedo ver lo que se carga con el Notepad++

Saludos